# How to run bundled javascript files in blazor web assembly?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, interopservices, asp.net-blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I have kept the bundled script files in  wwwroot folder of blazor_wasm app.

1. I added the file using script tags in index.html

```
    <script src="assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/scripts.bundle.js"></script>
```

2. I have put scripts.bundle.js code in a function callJS

   `function callJS() {/** bundled js**/}`
3. I called the function using js interops in a razor page but this is giving errors

   ```
   protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender){
       if (firstRender)
       {
           await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("callJS");
       }
    }
   ```

These are the errors

> The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task, a
>   task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable, or IAsyncEnumerator   wasm_app
>
> 'Index.OnAfterRenderAsync(bool)': return type must be 'Task' to match
>   overridden member 'ComponentBase.OnAfterRenderAsync(bool)'    wasm_app

Is this the correct way of running file or do I have to use another life cycle event??
I am using keen bootstrap theme which produces bundled js and css files using webpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple we just have to put the js interops code in MainLayout.razor page.That is how i solved it

Comment: Can you show this with an example that how did you achieve that? I also need to execute a static asset .js file similarly.

Comment: Copy your bundled js folder and paste in www.root folderin blazor wasm. Because Js need interops to run so I added this function on top of --> scripts.bundle.js file 


window.callBundleJS = () => {****code****} and call it in Mainlayout.razor page using OnAfterRenderAsync Life cycle method. The way I have done and also include that bundled js file in index.html